# Looping .CSV and drawing map Markers

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Trying to draw markers on a GoogleMap (`googleMap`). The properties are stored in a CSV file structured as `name`, `code` (which is used primarly as a snippet), `latitude` and `longitude`. This doesn't have any errors, but doesn't compile properly

```
    String name;
    String code; 
    String latitude;
    String longitude;
    String fileName;

    fileName = "sleepertrain5/assests/stations.csv";

    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = getAssets().open(fileName);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    try {
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
             String[] RowData = line.split(",");
             name = RowData[0];
             code = RowData[1];
             latitude= RowData[2];
             longitude=RowData[3];


             String latAmount=latitude;
             double amount1=Float.parseFloat(latAmount);

             String longAmount=latitude;
             double amount2=Float.parseFloat(longAmount);

             googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
             .position(new LatLng(amount1, amount2))
             .title(name)
             .snippet("Station code: "+ code));

        }
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        // handle exception
    }
    finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            // handle exception
        }
```

Any help as to how I would do this?

Comment: You say there are no errors so I take it "String longAmount=latitude;" that shouldn't be longitude

Comment: @Rafe still doesn't compile

Comment: Compiler usually give useful message about what's wrong when the compilation fails. What's the output when your project doesn't compile?

Comment: @nicopico I found the error now, it was a slight discrepancy in the csv that wasn't being handled correctly

Answer (score 0):

I've found the issue: there was a small error in one line of the CSV file which caused it to crash.